# How to add custom cert path to okhttp?

Tags: java, okhttp

For example if my cert is in

```
/etc/lipki/ca-bundle.crt
```

How do I set the cert path in okhttp?

In python request I can do something like this

```
        response = post(
            "my_url"
            data={
            },
            auth=("my_basic_username", "my_basic_password"),
            verify="/etc/lipki/ca-bundle.crt"
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .certificatePinner(new CertificatePinner.Builder()
    .add("my_url", "sha256/#") // replace with actual pin
    .build())
  .build();
```

The real values for your certificate should be used in instead of **my_url** and **#**.

Comment: what does # correspond?

the location of my cert like `/etc/lipki/ca-bundle.crt` ?

Comment: Yes, The SHA-256 hash of the certificate may be found using the command if you have the certificate file located in ```/etc/lipki/ca-bundle.crt```: ```openssl x509 -in /etc/lipki/ca-bundle.crt -noout -sha256 -fingerprint```

Comment: It is working or not